# Сделать прозрачным компонент TPanel delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть ли какие-нибудь свойства, или все нужно прописывать кодом?

Comment: а что значит прозрачным? можем вам его сделать одного цвета с родительским и отключить границы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У стандартного TPanel нету такого свойства, поэтому - только руками.

Или, можно взять готовый компонент TJvPanel из библиотеки [JVCL](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl), у которого такое свойство [есть](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/master/jvcl/run/JvPanel.pas#L282).

Answer (score 0):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, jpeg;

  // Хук для стандартной панели
type
  TPanel = class(ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

  // Пишем процедуру, которая отвечает за прозрачность стандартной панели
procedure TPanel.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

  // Перерисовываем стандартную панель
procedure TPanel.Paint;
var
  XBitMap: TBitMap;
  XOldDC: HDC;
  XRect: TRect;
begin
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    inherited Paint
  else
  begin
    XRect := ClientRect;
    XOldDC := Canvas.Handle;
    XBitMap := TBitMap.Create;
    try
      XBitMap.Height := Height;
      XBitMap.Width := Width;
      Canvas.Handle := XBitMap.Canvas.Handle;
      inherited Paint;
      RedrawWindow(Parent.Handle, @XRect, 0, RDW_ERASE or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_NOCHILDREN or RDW_UPDATENOW);
    finally
      Canvas.Handle := XOldDC;
      Canvas.BrushCopy(XRect, XBitMap, XRect, Color);
      XBitMap.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]